# Match columns and update other column

Tags: excel, match, formula, excel-2013

Let's say I have column A, B, C and D.

- A has: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 (ID's)
- B has: something specific to each number
- C has: same as B, it's specific to column A (which will be an ID)
- D has: same as column A, ID's which can be duplicates or unique.

What I want is to compare column A & D. If they are the SAME ID (e.g A has Id: 231 and D has id: 231), then put the value from B (which corresponds to the ID from A) into the E column. So, if id from A is a match with the id found on D column, to insert the "B" data into E.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Let's say I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "What do I want?" is not a programming question.

Comment: It's retorical. The question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a simple IF formula statement. 
IF is set up as follows: IF (conditional statement, what to do if true, what to do if false).

The final formula would be: `=IF(A2=D2,B2,"")`, in E2. Then just copy this down to all E cells in which this comparison is desired.

For more info: [Check out MS Support: IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)